# Exam ques. on how booleans are handled in cout

Tags: c++

I'm studying for upcoming exams and came across this past exam question which doesn't make sense to me.

Consider the following main function:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    cout << "x = " << x << ", (0 < x < 10) = " << (0 < x < 10) << endl;
    int x = 5;
    cout << "x = " << x << ", (0 < x < 10) = " << (0 < x < 10) << endl;
    int x = 10;
    cout << "x = " << x << ", (0 < x < 10) = " << (0 < x < 10) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When executed the program prints the following:

```
x = 0, (0 < x < 10) = 1
x = 5, (0 < x < 10) = 1
x = 10, (0 < x < 10) = 1
```

Explain exactly what has happened.

That's the question. As far as I know, the last line of output should be "x = 10, (0 < x < 10) = 0". What am I missing?

Comment: What is the order of evaluation of the `<` operators?

Comment: What's the question? Tell us which part of the program you do not understand.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What do you expect `0 < x < 10` to mean?

It doesn't check whether `x` is between `0` and `10`, if that's what you thought.

`<` is a binary operator, which follows operator evaluation rules (precedence and associativity).

So `0 < x < 10` actually means `(0 < x) < 10`. You'll need two checks to get the result you want (left to you).

Comment: Oh, of course! So each time it checks if 0 or 1 is less than 10 for true or false. Thanks, big help :)

Answer (score 3):

`0 < x < 10` does not do what you think it does. It does `( 0 < x ) < 10` which is not what you want. The result of `0 < x` ( which will be `true` or `false` ) is then checked with `< 10` which will also give result as `true` ( numerically equal to 1 ) or `false` ( numerically equal to 0 ).

You need

```
( 0 < x ) && ( x < 10 )
```

to check whether `x` in between them.

So, your first `cout` with `x=0` is same as `( 0 < 0 )` which gives false and then `0 < 10` ( false is numerically 0 ), and hence the result is 1.

Similarly, your second `cout` at `x=5` first gives result false and then with `0 < 10` , it gives true.

And finally, your last `cout` at `x=10` first results true, and again true, so result is 1.